# Why optimistic rollup chains can take a week, while ZK don't?

Tags: blockchain, security, rollups, finality

Optimistic and ZK rollups, both submit data to Ethereum or similar chain, but why do optimistic rollups take longer time then zk rollups? What's the core difference that causes this time difference?

Answer (score 4):

In a zk rollup, the sequencer submits a batch of transactions and a proof that the new state root was computed correctly.

In optimistic rollups, the sequencer only submits the batch of transactions and the proposed new state root. The new root is assumed to be valid unless proved otherwise. The 1 week delay is necessary so that other participants have time to challenge the sequencer, in case the new root is incorrect. Such a dispute is then settled on the main chain.

You can learn more about how such fraud proofs work [here](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/scaling/optimistic-rollups/#multi-round-interactive-proving).

Comment: does zkrollup submit proof first then batch of transactions, or vice versa. how does solidity code work in this submit and batch transactions ?